# Cartoon about the benefits/dangers of nuclear energy

Tags: story-identification, cartoon, educational

I watched this color cartoon back in school prior to 1995 in the USA, but I'm not sure how old it actually is.

The only scene I remember is a nuclear family (pardon the pun) seen from the rear. The family consists of a father dressed in a blue 1950s suit and fedora, a mom with blonde hair, and a boy. The boy gets a soft drink from a vending machine and sprouts 2 additional arms--to the delight of all three. The view changes and reveals that the mother's head is just a single giant eye and that the father also has 4 arms. There may have been a dog as well, with its own mutations.

Comment: Was it as educational cartoon?  The title seems to suggest it was.

Comment: And, just to be certain, not from the fallout game? :)

Comment: @Buzz We watched it while studying the "atomic age" but it wasn't a straight-up educational cartoon. I want to say it was satire but I'm really not sure.

Comment: @Seeds I've never played Fallout, and to be the best of my recollection, I've never watched any gameplay footage either.

Comment: The dog reminds me of the bit from Naked Gun where the commercial for the benefits of nuclear power ends with the family dog obviously having two tails that he's wagging, but the rest doesn't match.

Comment: You might investigate 'A is for Atom', a film from the '50s, I haven't watched it yet, but my recollection is that the humorous docu-vids in the fallout series were (loosly) based on stuff like that.